# getsockname() returns invalid-looking name

Tags: c++, sockets, socketpair

I'm new to socket programming. Having created a socket pair with `socketpair()`, I wanted to investigate what address the sockets are bound to. But when I try to determine this with `getsockname()`, I get an invalid-looking result.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int identifysock( int sd )
{
  std::ios_base::fmtflags mask = std::cout.flags();
  int ret_val = 0;
  std::cout << " === SD " << sd << " ===" << std::endl;
  struct sockaddr_un su;
  socklen_t addrlen = sizeof( sockaddr_un );
  std::cout << "before getsockname() addrlen == " << addrlen << std::endl;
  memset( &su, 0, sizeof( sockaddr_un ) );
  if ( getsockname( sd, (sockaddr*)&su, &addrlen ) )
  {
    std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
    ret_val = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "after getsockname() addrlen == " << addrlen << " name == " << su.sun_path << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::showbase << std::hex << (uint32_t)su.sun_path[0] << " " << (uint32_t)su.sun_path[1] << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout.flags(mask);
  return ret_val;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  int sd[2];
  if ( socketpair( AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sd ) )
  {
    std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  std::cout << "sd[ 0 ] == " << sd[ 0 ] << std::endl;
  std::cout << "sd[ 1 ] == " << sd[ 1 ] << std::endl;
  if ( identifysock( sd[ 0 ] ) )
  {
    return 1;
  }
  if ( identifysock( sd[ 1 ] ) )
  {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
>g++ -g main.cpp
>./a.out
sd[ 0 ] == 3
sd[ 1 ] == 4
 === SD 3 ===
before getsockname() addrlen == 110
after getsockname() addrlen == 2 name == 
0 0
 === SD 4 ===
before getsockname() addrlen == 110
after getsockname() addrlen == 2 name == 
0 0
```

Per my understanding, `getsockname()` is telling me there should be an address of length 2. But the two bytes starting at `su.sun_path` are `0` - surely this cannot be a valid address can it?

I know that `socketpair()` creates a pair of "unnamed" sockets - but I thought an "unnamed socket" just meant an abstract namespace, that was still some unique, non-NULL string thereof.

Can someone explain why this code outputs the observed invalid-looking namespace?

Comment: Nope, `socketpair` doesn't use the `AF_UNIX` abstract namespace. It really is unnamed.

Comment: I can't help but conjecture that for sockets to communicate, there must be some underlying "address" that is unique...otherwise, how can a channel of communication be established? I'm unclear. I thought, "perhaps unnamed can mean unprintable bytes, e.g. two `0` bytes." If so, I figured, if I did a second `socketpair()`, those sockets would use a _different_ unprintable address, but different than two `0` bytes. But that theory didn't pan out: the "address" of my second socketpair was also "two `0` bytes." Do you know how communication is done without some unique "address" per socketpair?

Comment: You can see the kernel implementation of [sys_socketpair](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.10/source/net/socket.c#L1290): it allocates two sockets in-memory, ties them together, adds them to the file descriptor table, and that's all.

Comment: Sure, there is somewhere an underlying "address", namely locations in kernel structures and addresses in kernel memory. However, the kernel will try very hard not to disclose that information to user space, so there doesn't necessarily have to be a way to get a unique name out of the kernel for your anonymous sockets.